# CSS Background not showing up (I had background before)

Tags: html, css

My CSS background won't show up in dreamweaver.
See, I used to have a picture as the background of the website, but I can't change it because it will just show black which is what I have as the background color.

Here is snippet of background code

```
.website {
background-position: 0%
%;
background-attachment: fixed;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(../images/craig_sarah_57.jpg);
background-color: #000000;
}
```

The above code with the background just shows black.

Comment: Careful about the `%;` line, you have to remove it.

Comment: Your code works fine for me.Double check the URL of image. See it's correct or not. I think it's the URL which is incorrect

Comment: I use dreamweaver, which points it to the image i want. Could dreamweaver mess this up?

Comment: "I use dreamweaver..." *\*shudder\** :P

Comment: You can't see image inside dreamweaver (design view), or when you test page??? Btw, code is ok: https://jsfiddle.net/vcma3auL/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is wrong. Look at the background-position line, you have % twice.

Comment: Which will cause the value to be ignored, which (all else being equal) will set it to the default value, which is `0% 0%`, which probably makes no difference.

Comment: Yeah I removed them, and no luck